# I have no users on my site yet the MySQL database connection count is always 10+

Tags: mysql, database, apache, connection

My database seems to have many open connections despite having no users on httpd.

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;
+-------+----------+--------------------+---------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id    | User     | Host               | db                  | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+-------+----------+--------------------+---------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 22865 | rdsadmin | localhost:51066    | mysql               | Sleep   |    8 |       | NULL             |
| 25098 | ubuntu   | 123.45.67.89:48060 | database_name_here! | Sleep   |  350 |       | NULL             |
| 25099 | ubuntu   | 123.45.67.89:48069 | database_name_here! | Sleep   | 3731 |       | NULL             |
| 25126 | ubuntu   | 123.45.67.89:49558 | database_name_here! | Sleep   |  349 |       | NULL             |
| 25161 | ubuntu   | 123.45.67.89:50770 | database_name_here! | Sleep   |  289 |       | NULL             |
| 26583 | ubuntu   | 123.45.67.89:37593 | database_name_here! | Sleep   | 4550 |       | NULL             |
| 29729 | ubuntu   | 123.45.67.89:49280 | database_name_here! | Sleep   |  953 |       | NULL             |
| 29737 | ubuntu   | 123.45.67.89:49489 | database_name_here! | Sleep   |  953 |       | NULL             |
| 29738 | ubuntu   | 123.45.67.89:49490 | database_name_here! | Sleep   |  349 |       | NULL             |
| 29755 | ubuntu   | 123.45.67.89:50674 | database_name_here! | Sleep   | 2751 |       | NULL             |
| 29759 | ubuntu   | 123.45.67.89:50892 | database_name_here! | Sleep   |  600 |       | NULL             |
| 35600 | ubuntu   | 123.45.67.89:49677 | NULL                | Query   |    0 | NULL  | SHOW PROCESSLIST |
+-------+----------+--------------------+---------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
```

I don't understand how there are so many connections. I'm using amazon EC2 with RDS, apache/mysql/PHP with PDO. I have persistent connections "on", but I thought this simply cached the connection. It seems somehow 10 connections remain open constantly even though there are 1-2 users on my site at any given time.

What is the cause of this, and how can I fix it? Is this normal behavior, are there a minimum amount of connections that MySQL keeps open to handle different users? I cannot seem to find any information on how to analyze what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'll have a connection pool from your application server (Apache httpd, nginx, etc.) to your database. These stay open all the time so there's no reconnection required when a request comes in. Remember, connecting to the database can take several seconds, but using an active connection takes zero time.

Why would you want to "fix" this? It's a feature of a modern application stack. If they're not running queries, there's no issue.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of "too many connection" errors, and I'm wondering if somehow my PHP code is configured incorrectly such that I am generating many connections for a small amount of users.

Comment: You could try increasing the number of connections allowed on your server to avoid this problem. Often the default is really low. Plus, check the connection pool size.

Comment: I'm still having this problem. The MySQL seems to open 10 connections for each new database I'm connecting to, but won't go over 30. For example, when I run a cron to write to the DB every minute, it opens 10 connections for that DB, but when I try to go to the site on the web it puts the `Error connecting to database: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections` error message in my face. Why is MySQL opening 10 connections to each DB then not using any of them? They're all under the "sleep" command.

Comment: You need to close them too when you're done with them, so they return to the pool. With PHP that happens automatically at the end of the script if I'm not mistaken, so ensure that you don't have any long running scripts...